# How to draw the normal distribution of a barplot with log x axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to draw a lognormal distribution of a given bar plot.
Here's the code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

inter = 33
x = np.logspace(-2, 1, num=3*inter+1)
yaxis = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01,0.03,0.3,0.75,1.24,1.72,2.2,3.1,3.9,
         4.3,4.9,5.3,5.6,5.87,5.96,6.01,5.83,5.42,4.97,4.60,4.15,3.66,3.07,2.58,2.19,1.90,1.54,1.24,1.08,0.85,0.73,
         0.84,0.59,0.55,0.53,0.48,0.35,0.29,0.15,0.15,0.14,0.12,0.14,0.15,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.03,0.03,0.03, 0.02,
         0.02,0.03,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.01,0,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x[:-1], yaxis, width=np.diff(x), align="center", ec='k', color='w')

ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Diameter (mm)', fontsize='12')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of Total Particles (%)', fontsize='12')
plt.ylim(0,8)
plt.xlim(0.01, 10)
fig.set_size_inches(12, 12)
plt.savefig("Test.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Resulting plot:

[image: current plot]

What I'm trying to do is to draw the Probability Density Function exactly like the one shown in red in the graph below:

[image: desired plot]

Comment: Where's the part where you try to draw the red line?

Comment: Don't mix and match oo commands and pyplot ones

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to convert everything to logspace, with `u = log10(x)`. Then draw the density histogram in there. And also calculate a kde in the same space. Everything gets drawn as `y` versus `u`. When we have `u` at a top twin axes, `x` can stay at the bottom. Both axes get aligned by setting the same xlims, but converted to logspace on the top axis. The top axis can be hidden to get the desired result.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

inter = 33
u = np.linspace(-2, 1, num=3*inter+1)
x = 10**u
us = np.linspace(u[0], u[-1], 500)
yaxis = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01,0.03,0.3,0.75,1.24,1.72,2.2,3.1,3.9,
         4.3,4.9,5.3,5.6,5.87,5.96,6.01,5.83,5.42,4.97,4.60,4.15,3.66,3.07,2.58,2.19,1.90,1.54,1.24,1.08,0.85,0.73,
         0.84,0.59,0.55,0.53,0.48,0.35,0.29,0.15,0.15,0.14,0.12,0.14,0.15,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.03,0.03,0.03, 0.02,
         0.02,0.03,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.01,0,0]
yaxis = np.array(yaxis)

# reconstruct data from the given frequencies
u_data = np.repeat((u[:-1] + u[1:]) / 2, (yaxis * 100).astype(np.int))

kde = stats.gaussian_kde((u[:-1]+u[1:])/2, weights=yaxis, bw_method=0.2)
total_area = (np.diff(u)*yaxis).sum()  # total area of all bars; divide by this area to normalize

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.bar(u[:-1], yaxis, width=np.diff(u), align="edge", ec='k', color='w', label='frequencies')
ax2.plot(us, total_area*kde(us), color='crimson', label='kde')
ax2.plot(us, total_area * stats.norm.pdf(us, u_data.mean(), u_data.std()), color='dodgerblue', label='lognormal')
ax2.legend()

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Diameter (mm)', fontsize='12')
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage of Total Particles (%)', fontsize='12')
ax.set_ylim(0,8)
xlim = np.array([0.01,10])
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax2.set_xlim(np.log10(xlim))
ax2.set_xticks([])  # hide the ticks at the top

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Apparently this also can be achieved directly without explicitly using `u` (at the cost of being slightly more cryptic):

```py
x = np.logspace(-2, 1, num=3*inter+1)
xs = np.logspace(-2, 1, 500)

total_area = (np.diff(np.log10(x))*yaxis).sum()  # total area of all bars; divide by this area to normalize
kde = gaussian_kde((np.log10(x[:-1])+np.log10(x[1:]))/2, weights=yaxis, bw_method=0.2)

ax.bar(x[:-1], yaxis, width=np.diff(x), align="edge", ec='k', color='w')
ax.plot(xs, total_area*kde(np.log10(xs)), color='crimson')

ax.set_xscale('log')
```

Note that the bandwidth set for `gaussian_kde` is a somewhat arbitrarily value. Larger values give a more equalized curve, smaller values keep closer to the data. Some experimentation can help.